# Is refresh token limited for each user and client id

Tags: oauth-2.0

In OAuth2, I think for each user and client id, the refresh token should be unique or limited, or the database may be too big, or we need extra effort to remove token from database.

As a newbie in OAuth2, I'm not quite sure for this. Could anyone give me some link about the storage of tokens。 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refresh token should be unique for user and client id, also for different scopes.

Here are some suggestions:

1. Reuse refresh token:
   For example, the same user authorize the same client with same scopes via authorization code grant flow, you can search current refresh tokens in your store that matches these query condition, update the expire time and return it, so you don need to created a new one.
2. Clean up expired token:
   You can schedule a periodic task to clean up expired token(If refresh token expires, you should also delete the access token it issued).

As for the store, I think LDAP and Cassandra will be proper to storing/retrieving tokens.